# GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object [some obscure closure] with class [another obscure closure] to [your business interface/class]

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I have a loosely-coupled code structure that I'm using to power my Katalon Studio tests. It consists of a `TaskInfo` that has a `List` of `PayRateInterface`s. Also, `TaskInfo` implements `TaskInterface` (as there will be a class that has `TaskInterface`) in the future.

At the very first line of this method in `TaskInfo`:

```
@Override
public PayRateInterface getMostRecentPayRate() {
    PayRateInterface newestPayrate = payRates.get(0);
    for (PayRateInterface payRate : payRates) {
        if (payRate.getTimestamp().after(newestPayrate.getTimestamp())) {
            newestPayrate = payRate;
        }
    }
    return newestPayrate;
}
```

, I get the runtime exception:

```
Test Cases/AddInvalidTasks FAILED because (of) org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Script1530218543089$_run_closure1@1358b28e' with class 'Script1530218543089$_run_closure1' to class 'com.ezsoftpos.beans.employee.tasks_and_rates.PayRateInterface'
```

`PayRateInterface` is defined as follows:

```
public interface PayRateInterface {
    double getPayRate();
    Date getTimestamp();
}
```

The rest of my classes and interfaces are defined as follows:

`PayRateInfo` :

```
package com.ezsoftpos.beans.employee.tasks_and_rates

import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords

import internal.GlobalVariable

import MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

/**
 * Represents a pay rate. 
 * @author mwarren
 *
 */
public class PayRateInfo implements PayRateInterface  {
    private double payRate;
    private Date timestamp = new Date();

    /**
     * No-args constructor
     */
    public PayRateInfo() {
    }

    /**
     * For just-added pay rates. 
     */
    public PayRateInfo(double payRate) {
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }

    /**
     * For retrieving a pay rate.
     * @param payRate
     * @param timestamp
     */
    public PayRateInfo(double payRate, Date timestamp) {
        this.payRate = payRate;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public double getPayRate() {
        return payRate;
    }
    public void setPayRate(double payRate) {
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PayRateInfo [payRate=" + payRate + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(payRate);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((timestamp == null) ? 0 : timestamp.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PayRateInfo other = (PayRateInfo) obj;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(payRate) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.payRate))
            return false;
        if (timestamp == null) {
            if (other.timestamp != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!timestamp.equals(other.timestamp))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

`TaskInterface` :

```
package com.ezsoftpos.beans.employee.tasks_and_rates

import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords

import internal.GlobalVariable

import MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

public interface TaskInterface {
    PayRateInterface getMostRecentPayRate();
}
```

`TaskInfo` :

```
package com.ezsoftpos.beans.employee.tasks_and_rates

import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import com.ezsoftpos.beans.employee.permission_groups.PermissionGroupInterface
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords

import internal.GlobalVariable

import MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

/**
 * POJO for the state of a Task. 
 * @author mwarren
 *
 */
public class TaskInfo implements TaskInterface {
    private List<PermissionGroupInterface> permissionGroups = new LinkedList<PermissionGroupInterface>();
    private List<PayRateInterface> payRates = new LinkedList<PayRateInterface>();
    private boolean isActive = true;
    private String name;

    /**
     * No-args constructor. 
     */
    public TaskInfo() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     */
    public TaskInfo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param payRates
     */
    public TaskInfo(String name, List<PayRateInterface> payRates) {
        this.payRates = payRates;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param payRates
     * @param permissionGroups
     */
    public TaskInfo(String name, List<PayRateInterface> payRates, List<PermissionGroupInterface> permissionGroups) {
        this(payRates);
        this.permissionGroups = permissionGroups;
    }


    @Override
    public PayRateInterface getMostRecentPayRate() {
        PayRateInterface newestPayrate = payRates.get(0);
        for (PayRateInterface payRate : payRates) {
            if (payRate.getTimestamp().after(newestPayrate.getTimestamp())) {
                newestPayrate = payRate;
            }
        }
        return newestPayrate;
    }




    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<PermissionGroupInterface> getPermissionGroups() {
        return permissionGroups;
    }




    public void setPermissionGroups(List<PermissionGroupInterface> permissionGroups) {
        this.permissionGroups = permissionGroups;
    }




    public List<PayRateInterface> getPayRates() {
        return payRates;
    }




    public void setPayRates(List<PayRateInterface> payRates) {
        this.payRates = payRates;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TaskInfo [permissionGroups=" + permissionGroups + ", payRates=" + payRates + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((payRates == null) ? 0 : payRates.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((permissionGroups == null) ? 0 : permissionGroups.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        TaskInfo other = (TaskInfo) obj;
        if (payRates == null) {
            if (other.payRates != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!payRates.equals(other.payRates))
            return false;
        if (permissionGroups == null) {
            if (other.permissionGroups != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!permissionGroups.equals(other.permissionGroups))
            return false;
        return true;
    };
}
```

**Use Case**

I tried to say

```
TaskInfo noName = new TaskInfo('', Arrays.asList({ 
        new PayRateInfo(15.00)
    }))
```

and then was like

```
noName.getMostRecentPayRate()
```

What, if anything, am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `payRates` contain? I think your problem lies there

Comment: It is a `private` member of `TaskInfo` and is a `List<PayRateInterface>`. It is declared as such: `private List<PayRateInterface> payRates = new LinkedList<PayRateInterface>()`

Comment: Yes, but what have you put in it?

Comment: Do you want to see the full class/interface definitions?

Comment: I'm about to post them...

Comment: What do you pass as `payRates` to the constructor? Or are you adding payrates at run time? How are you filling the payRates list?

Comment: Groovy doesn't care about your generics at run time.  And it looks from the error like you're putting closures into a `List<PayRateInterface>`

Comment: I feel dumb; /* it was accidentally a closure; // I am so used to Java */

I provided the use case.

Comment: Don't feel dumb, we got there in the end  maybe delete this question if you want? Glad you got it sorted  have fun!